# gsoap ANSI C - Using gsoap defined ANSI C Client-side call stub correctly

Tags: c, soap, gsoap

I am new to using gsoap.  I have 4 small successes using c++ only, however am constrained by my current project to set source code generation options to create pure ANSI C (not c++).  I cannot seem to successfully call the service, the error return is 0xC0000005 and given the following code snippets, can anyone make a suggestion as to what I should do differently:

**Snippets include**
    1. client-side function definition,
    2. ns7 structure def,
    3. simple calling application:
Thank you,

***Here is the client side call:***

```
#include "soapH.h"  
#include "addressByAccount_ExtWS_BPELSOAP.nsmap"

SOAP_FMAC5 int SOAP_FMAC6 soap_call___ns1__accountsBPEL(struct soap *soap, const char *soap_endpoint, const char *soap_action, struct _ns7__accounts *ns7__accounts, struct     _ns9__accountsResponse *ns9__accountsResponse)  
{         
        struct __ns1__accountsBPEL soap_tmp___ns1__accountsBPEL;  
        if (!soap_endpoint)    
            soap_endpoint = "http://cctest3-v.physio-control.com:8080/ccx/addressByAccount-ExtWS-BPEL";    
        if (!soap_action)  
        soap_action = "http://www.physio-control.com/addressByAccount-ExtWS-BPEL/1.0/accounts";  
    soap->encodingStyle = NULL;  
    soap_tmp___ns1__accountsBPEL.ns7__accounts = ns7__accounts;  
    soap_begin(soap);  
    soap_serializeheader(soap);
    soap_serialize___ns1__accountsBPEL(soap, &soap_tmp___ns1__accountsBPEL);
    if (soap_begin_count(soap))
            return soap->error;
    if (soap->mode & SOAP_IO_LENGTH)
    {   if (soap_envelope_begin_out(soap)
         || soap_putheader(soap)
         || soap_body_begin_out(soap)
         || soap_put___ns1__accountsBPEL(soap, &soap_tmp___ns1__accountsBPEL, "-ns1:accountsBPEL", NULL)
         || soap_body_end_out(soap)
         || soap_envelope_end_out(soap))
             return soap->error;
    }
    if (soap_end_count(soap))
        return soap->error;
    if (soap_connect(soap, soap_endpoint, soap_action)
     || soap_envelope_begin_out(soap)
     || soap_putheader(soap)
     || soap_body_begin_out(soap)
     || soap_put___ns1__accountsBPEL(soap, &soap_tmp___ns1__accountsBPEL, "-ns1:accountsBPEL", NULL)
     || soap_body_end_out(soap)
     || soap_envelope_end_out(soap)
     || soap_end_send(soap))
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    if (!ns9__accountsResponse)
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    soap_default__ns9__accountsResponse(soap, ns9__accountsResponse);
    if (soap_begin_recv(soap)
     || soap_envelope_begin_in(soap)
     || soap_recv_header(soap)
     || soap_body_begin_in(soap))
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    soap_get__ns9__accountsResponse(soap, ns9__accountsResponse, "ns9:accountsResponse", "");
    if (soap->error)
        return soap_recv_fault(soap, 0);
    if (soap_body_end_in(soap)
     || soap_envelope_end_in(soap)
     || soap_end_recv(soap))
        return soap_closesock(soap);
    return soap_closesock(soap);
}
```

***Here is the ns7 structure:***

```
struct _ns7__accounts
{
    int __sizeaccountNumber;    /* sequence of elements <accountNumber> */
    char **accountNumber;   /* required element of type xsd:string */
    char *requestIDTrackingForESB;  /* optional attribute of type xsd:string */
};
```

***Here is a simple application calling service using client-side call:***

```
struct _ns7__accounts in, *pIn;
struct _ns9__accountsResponse out, *pOut;
int main(void)
{
    struct soap *soap = soap_new();

    //used to populate char ** in pIn
    char *pNumber=malloc(sizeof("00000201"));
    strcpy(pNumber, "00000201");

    pOut = &out;
    pIn = &in;

    pIn->__sizeaccountNumber = sizeof("00000201");
    pIn->accountNumber = &pNumber;
    pIn->requestIDTrackingForESB = malloc(sizeof(""));
    strcpy(pIn->requestIDTrackingForESB,"");

    if (soap_call___ns1__accountsBPEL(soap, "", "", pIn, pOut)== SOAP_OK)
    {
        printf("Soap OK...");
    }
    else  
    {
        printf(pIn->requestIDTrackingForESB);
        soap_print_fault(soap, stderr);
    }
    soap_end(soap);
    soap_free(soap);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know gSOAP, but I find it odd to pass `""` for `soap_endpoint` and `soap_action`. Maybe it works with `soap_call___ns1__accountsBPEL(soap, NULL, NULL, pIn, pOut)`, seeing that inside the function, the values are replaced by something when they are NULL.

Comment: The "" entry for _soap_endpoint_ and _soap_action_ was only the most recent.  I have tried NULL and 0 for these arguments also, all with the same effect. - thanks, Ryk

Answer (score 1):

```
pIn->__sizeaccountNumber = sizeof("00000201");
```

`__sizeaccountNumber` should be set to the size of the array (1), not to the size of the first member in the array. Because a string is null terminated, there is no need to specify the size of a string.

And as already commented by pmg, don't pass `""` for soap_endpoint and soap_action. You can see in the function it defines defaults for those parameters, but only if you pass `0` (or `NULL`).

```
if (!soap_endpoint)    
  soap_endpoint = "http://cctest3-v.physio-control.com:8080/ccx/addressByAccount-ExtWS-BPEL";    
if (!soap_action)  
  soap_action = "http://www.physio-control.com/addressByAccount-ExtWS-BPEL/1.0/accounts";
```